# Push a git branch to a remote server which has not got git installed

Tags: git, bash, unix, ftp

I have a shared hosting account which I have both SSH and FTP access to, hover I do not have root access, and the server does not have git installed.
I am curious as to how feasible it is to set up a watcher script that monitors whether I have committed/merged to branch master (locally), and upload the master branch via FTP to the remote server.

I could do it manually (without the watcher script), perhaps with a bash script (I'm running Linux Mint) if creating a watcher is too complex, but I have no idea how to do it either way.

Comment: You don't need a watcher script. Git has [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that will allow you trigger on an event in the git repo (such as a `git commit`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone has already had the same conundrum, his [solution is on Github](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp).

It's all Pythony, but even if it doesn't work for you, should give you and idea of where to start.

And there is always [sitecopy](http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/why.html).

Comment: Well... In the middle of uploading the web server crashed... Damn :/

Comment: Actually, I was IP banned. Contacted support and got unblocked, *If you are to use this software, be careful as to input your correct password*

Comment: @Der : welcome to fun with network scripts.  :)   I try to test things out with a box on which I have root.  If nothing else, you could test it on your own machine by ftping to 127.0.0.1  You might want to switch to key-based authentication if this is a regular thing.

Comment: Yeah, probably should have done that :) I'm fairly new to thing kind of thing (although I was already testing on a local server, but I prefer testing on a real server, as you can get a feel for load times.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp#readme. Its a nice and simple shell scipt for uploading over FTP (no dependencies on any other languages). It does not require git to be installed on the server side.